# How to remove a class when others are slide Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with number of rows that some of rows are hidden and only visible when "show" button clicked. My question is how can i remove class rotate from arrow when another row is slide down? Here is my snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('rotati')
    var content = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content");
    $(".content").not(content).slideUp();
    content.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
.rotati img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('rotati')
    $('.show').not($(this)).parent().removeClass('rotati')
    var content = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content");
    $(".content").not(content).slideUp();
    content.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding:0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;

}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display:none;
}
.rotati img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Add `$('.show').not($(this)).parent().removeClass('rotati')`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @stackbaz glad to help mate close the OP by clicking the check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can change this:

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass('rotati')
```

to this:

```
$('.parentRow td').removeClass('rotati');
$(this).parent().addClass('rotati');
```

See demo below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.parentRow td').removeClass('rotati');
    $(this).parent().addClass('rotati');
    var content = $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".content");
    $(".content").not(content).slideUp();
    content.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.subRow {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
}
.content {
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  display: none;
}
.rotati img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption>Test Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr align="center" class="parentRow">
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parentRow">
      <td><a href="#" class="show">SHOW <img src="http://user.efeh.com/images/arrow-left.png"/></a>
      </td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
      <td>test cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```